# What is the colon used for in yii CDbCommand query parameters?

Tags: php, yii

We know we can build a query in yii using CDbCommand like

```
where('id=:id1 or id=:id2', array(':id1'=>1, ':id2'=>2))
```

I find this in *yii-guide-1.1.15* on page 91.

While in fact, the following style will also work:

```
where('id=:id1 or id=:id2', array('id1'=>1, 'id2'=>2))
```

Can anybody tell what's the difference? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Makes no difference,  you can either use with `:` or without `:` when you send the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its safe to apply Leading colon before parameter name, because its required, but if you will miss this leading colon , then PHP internally append colon before parameter name.

So best way is this

```
where('id=:id1 or id=:id2', array(':id1'=>1, ':id2'=>2))
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much and you are the first one to give an answer to me.:-)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) and to improve performance of executing repeatedly used SQL statements, one can "prepare" an SQL statement with optional parameter placeholders that are to be replaced with the actual parameters during the parameter binding process.

The parameter placeholders can be either named (represented as unique tokens) or unnamed (represented as question marks). Call [CDbCommand::bindParam()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindParam) or CDbCommand::bindValue() to replace these placeholders with the actual parameters. The parameters do not need to be quoted: the underlying database driver does it for you. Parameter binding must be done before the SQL statement is executed.

Comment: Thank you and this is exactly the answer I wanted. I just argued with one of my team member about this.And so it's usually helpful referencing docs other than coding blindly by thinking "seems working well".I'd like to click the up arrow for this answer by I don't have the reputation yet.Sorry~